# How to list all files inside assets folder in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am a newbie to React Native myself.
My requirement is to be able to list a set of files that are stored inside the ./assets/ directory. This directory has child directories inside, which then have .mp3 files inside them. I need to extract them as items into a list (ex: flatList, etc).
I am using Expo v46 with React Native v0.69.4, and testing out on iOS simulator.

I tried with this:

```
import { soundAssets }  from '../../assets/sounds_library/sounds_first';

const loadAssets = async () => 

    await Promise.all(
        soundAssets.map(sound => Asset.fromModule(sound).downloadAsync()),
    );
```

With this, the project does not compile !

The only other way, I found was using 'react-native-fs' but it seems to support only "Pure" React Native. I need to have this project on Expo.

My metro.config.js includes:

```
resolver: {
            assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
            sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg", "cjs", "mp3"]    
        }};
```

What is the best way to list out all files inside a folder structure in an assets folder in the application ?
Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

try this

in my case i have `assets/www` folder

In your app:

```js
const getAllFilePathsFromFolder = async (folderName) => {
  const reader = await RNFS.readDirAssets(folderName);

  const directories = reader.filter((item) => item.isDirectory());
  const files = reader.filter((item) => item.isFile()).map((file) => file.path);

  const directioriesFilesPromises = directories.map((dir) => (
    getAllFilePathsFromFolder(dir.path)
  ));

  const directioriesFiles = await (await Promise.all(directioriesFilesPromises)).flat(Infinity);

  return [...files, ...directioriesFiles];
};


 const files = await getAllFilePathsFromFolder('www');
 
 
 const result = files.filter((filename) => (filename.includes('.mp3')));
```

result its array of your `.mp3` files paths

Comment: Using RNFS is not an option for me as I already mentioned in the question, as it requires ejection out of Expo, and I am required to stay on Expo.